# Render angular ui calendar from other controller using ng-click

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, ui-calendar

I am using Angularjs Calendar UI for creating events scheduler calendar. Initially Calendar is hidden and on switch toggle it is displayed. But calendar is not rendered until next or prev month button is pressed.

```
app.controller('toggleController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(event) {
      angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.calendar-container')).css({display:'block'});
  };
}]);
```

so i want to call render function from calendar ui controller so that it is rendered on toggling view from above controller

```
app.controller('CalendarCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', function($scope,  $compile, $timeout, uiCalendarConfig) {
    /* Change View */
    $scope.renderCalendar = function(calendar) {
      $timeout(function() {
        if(uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar]){
          uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('render');
        }
      });
    };
}]);
```

I tried calling renderCalendar function using `$rootscope` but I get below error

> `$timeout not defined` or `uiCalendarConfig not defined`  etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dependency declaration and injection has to be same and in-order.

Do it like :

```
app.controller('CalendarCtrl', ['$scope','$compile', '$timeout', 'uiCalendarConfig`, function($scope,  $compile, $timeout, uiCalendarConfig) {\\
```

Comment: I tried. No errors now but its not triggered now.. $rootScope.$emit and $rootScope.$on not triggered

Comment: I don't see any `$rootScope.$emit` in your posted code..?,

Comment: glad to help u:)